# Role to Module Permissions in BIM360/Acc assignment

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am working on a BIM360 solution that uses api calls to assign roles and permissions to users for a project,
And also works on removing access to modules once it is no longer required. But the issue is there is no direct correlation maintained between role and module permissions from the api. If you use the post bulk call it would just allow you to manipulate rights of document_management and project_administration services.
like below: [ {

```
"email": "abc@gmail.com",
"services": {
    "document_management": {
        "access_level": "user"
    }
}

,
"company_id": "companyid",
"industry_roles": \[ "roleid"
\]
```

}

] I can assign the lowest permissions of user at document management. But the highest go as admin at project administration and not glue services or design services or assets etc. if i use simple post call the thing is I can assign rights on individual users and individual service modules. So if there are x users and y modules and z projects in a hubs,
the complexity will become axyz which is like O(n^4) not really helpful. Not to mention these are post calls and not patch calls. So In case I want to reduce rights on a service module,
I can't do it, because patch call only allows role changes and not service access changes.
Also,
there is no delete user from project api exposed for BIM360,
so that I can delete a user and add him again with new rights. Can anyone please help me with two things: 1) how to reduce the complexity of the permission assignment. 2) how to reduce module access permissions.
Thanks In Advance.
Akanchha